# Assert.IsType<> Failure in Xunit using Mock framework

Tags: async-await, moq, xunit

I got the following error when I ran unit test for my class using Xunit Moq framework.

Created mock objects for each parameter that takes by the constructor and invoked the method in the class. The expected result is to be the List of elements. Then I am trying to Assert the result as IsType>(result)

The following was the Issue when I followed the above steps:

> Assert.IsType() Failure
>   Expected: System.Collections.Generic.List1****, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] 
>   Actual: Castle.Proxies.IList`1Proxy

Answer (score 0):

Well, judging by the error it seems that the list you are asserting is a mocked list. The "Object" property of a Mock object is always of type Castle.Proxies...

Simply set up the mock that returns this particular List to return an actual List. Then the Assert should work.